# SQL: Calculating Percent Missing of all the columns in a table

Tags: sql, percentage, missing-data

I've got a table with, lets say columns: "A" "B" "C" and "D" containing over a million rows.
I'd like to calculate how many percentage of data is missing per column.

So the outcome should look like:

"Column Name";"PctMissing"

"A";0.05

"B";0.30

"C";0.40

"D";0.11

What would the SQL Statement look like?

With kind regards,

Lazzanova

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2):

One method is conditional aggregation:

```
select avg(case when a is null then 1.0 else 0 end) as missing_a,
       avg(case when b is null then 1.0 else 0 end) as missing_b,
       avg(case when c is null then 1.0 else 0 end) as missing_c,
       avg(case when d is null then 1.0 else 0 end) as missing_d
from t;
```

Notes:

- This produces ratios rather than percentages.  If you really prefer percentages, use `100.0` rather than `1.0`.
- This puts the results in columns rather than rows.  In most databases this is more efficient (the table is scanned only once).

You can use `union all` for different rows as a general practice:

```
select 'a', avg(case when a is null then 1.0 else 0 end) as missing
from t
union all
select 'b', avg(case when b is null then 1.0 else 0 end) as missing
from t
union all
. . .;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Now I've learned how to use the avg function.
Is there a way to get the column names as rows and the missing percentage as a second column?